# Is there way to run multiple sockets objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

I'm setting-up my application so that it has two socket objects
(one is for TCP and the other is for UDP).
Each object runs at different functions which has while True loop in it.
I've tried multi-threading which doesn't help (the first defined function is only running)
And I need to run both sockets from one file and both TCP and UPD simultaneously.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Thankyou.

Comment: Are you sending UDP or receiving?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/select.html ?

Comment: both sending and receiving (TCP and UDP)

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Twisted.  For example, here's a program that runs two separate web servers at the same time:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet.task import react
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.static import File

def main(reactor):
    reactor.listenTCP(10000, Site(File(b"/foo")))
    reactor.listenTCP(20000, Site(File(b"/bar")))
    return Deferred()

react(main, [])
```